# What is correct way of closing list elements?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I tried to validate my code on W3 validator and its showing errors like - ***No li element in scope but a li end tag seen.***
It's bootstrap dropdown menu, that i found on bootstrap examples.

Am i missing something about list elements?

```
<li class="menu-open">
                <a href="#" class="drop-width dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collections</a>
                <ul class="drop-menu dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="drop-menu dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2014</a>
                        <ul class="drop-menu dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="drop-menu dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2014</a>
                        <ul class="drop-menu dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="drop-menu dropdown-submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="drop-menu dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2014</a>
                        <ul class="drop-menu dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: You have <li> as children of a parent <li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking to have another ul inside your submenu items

```
<ul class="drop-menu dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Krizs I answered that first! Anyway... Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 2):

In the following code:

```
<li class="drop-menu dropdown-submenu">
    <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
```

You definitely cannot have `<li>` as a direct descendant of itself. That's one major issue and apart from that, try having all the closing tags right. Bootstrap examples are validated perfectly.